# Jest Failed after upgrading : _jestWatcher(...).TestWatcher is not a constructor

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jestjs, upgrade, react-testing-library

I have been working on upgrading a NextJS projet from version 9 to 12 :

During the updates, i had to update React from 16 to 17 and Jest from 23 to 28.

My final package.Json looks like :

```
"next": "^12.2.3",
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/react-hooks": "^3.2.1",

    "jest": "^28.1.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^28.1.3",
```

Till now everything works "almost" fine (few test failed after upgrade) with @testing-library/react V10.

When I upgraded the @testing-library/react to V13 : I got a this error :

TypeError: _jestWatcher(...).TestWatcher is not a constructor. Have been searching for this error but I did not find anything.

Does anyone face this error recently ?

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPTCg.png)

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO, please prefer post code than image : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: `TestWatcher` is moved to `jest-watcher`. I guess there is some libraries list `jest` as its peer dependency and imports `TestWatcher` from `jest` directly.